# How do I flip a single letter within a word or phrase in a given text box?

Tags: inkscape, text

It seems like this should be very intuitive.  I can change the color, alignment, rotation, etc of a single letter.  However, I have not found a way to flip a letter horizontally without affecting the entire word or phrase.  The only workaround I have accomplished is creating a separate text box with only the letter I want to flip, flipping the letter, aligning that letter with the word in the other text box, making the letter in that word the same color as the background and then grouping the two objects together.  However, that has disadvantages.  Especially when you want to change colors of the text or add effects.

[Edit - I neglected to mention that I tried copying and pasting the reversed letter into the original text box.  Unfortunately, it pastes such that it is no longer reversed.]

Actually, I just thought of a possible solution.  However, it would be a convoluted process.  So, I'd like to see what people here advise first.  Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE!

Comment: Thank you @Mensch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is another workaround, but without placement and color problems.

Duplicate your text box. Hide the original in the Objects panel.

Select the duplicate and apply Path > Object to path. You get a group of paths which can be edited. Everyone can be selected separately in the objects panel.

If you must change the writing you can delete the path group version and enable the original in the objects panel.

An example:
[image]

The original is moved upwards and shown, too. One letter in the path group is flipped.

If you have several textboxes it surely pays off to rename the textboxes and path groups in the objects panel to something else than text01234. It happens by double clicking an object in the objects panel.

Comment: This is a possible solution and is less convoluted than what I was thinking, but let me see if there's a simpler one.  Thank you for responding though.

Comment: I guess someone could write what you need - a person who talks XML, knows your problem and is willing to answer. If you understand XML (=the description language used in SVG files) you may find what to write in the XML view window of Inkscape.

Comment: I have enough of an understanding of XML to be able to edit existing code, but I'm not sure I could do my own.  It might, and I do stress might, be easier to create my own font based on an existing one with that one letter reversed.  Then again, I do not anticipate needing to do this again unless I do another illustration using the current Simple Minds logo style.  If they like it, I may indeed.  I'm doing this as a fan.  I was not hired by the band or their management.

Comment: @DavidLazarus - this is the simplest way. There's nothing in SVG which will allow for one letter within a text box to be reversed. You'd need to convert to outlines as this answer suggests.

Comment: OK.  After trying my more convoluted process only to realize it wasn't going to accomplish my goal, I have decided that this is, in fact, the best solution.  Thank you.

Comment: @BillyKerr a single letter within a textbox can be rotated via the user interface. It generates to the XML something which is called "span" and contains a rotation command. Is there any command which flips that letter - like scaling horizontally to -100% (I have seen that somewhere, but I do not know how to say it in XML nor understand the needed other conditions). I guess one should only replace the rotation with something else which flips.

Comment: @user28701 Not as far as I know. In any case, even if there was, it would still be more complex than your solution which is by far the simplest.

Comment: The scaling trick is shown in programming sites; an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9338447/android-flip-image-in-xml- no idea how to say it in Inkscape. But one could generate the place in the code for the scaling by applying "rotate a letter" at first.

Answer (score 1):

Another workaround is to use the **Split text** extension as follows:

- Select your text.
- From **Extensions** menu > **Text** choose **Split text**
- Under the options tab, select the split to be `Letters`.
- Press Apply.
- Align the right and the left-most letters with the original text. Then distribute the interior letters uniformly.
- Flip the desired letter.
- Group the result.

[image: Recording of the steps]

Comment: Cool!  Thanks!  I'll keep it in mind.  Though I think creating a path is probably just as easy.